# jQuery - Cant use clientX to change a css attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my problem

I want to move a div from its position to the mouses position when i mouseover an element.

Almost like a "tooltip", but when i mouseover it doesnt move. Here is the code:

```
$item.mouseover(function (){

//make visible
   $tooltip.show();

    //change left and top values to mouse values
   $tooltip.css("left","event.clientX + 'px'");
   $tooltip.css("top","200px");         
 });
```

The "event.clientX + 'px'" doesn't seem to work, is there anyway i can get this to work?
The top attribute is changed without problems but I cant get the mouse value to work.

how can i change the item.left & .top values to that of the mouses?

ty in advance!

-Thaiscorpion

edit:
Wow thats for the really super fast answers im gonna trythem right now thanx!!

Comment: Be sure that the tooltip has `position: absolute;` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating the event object as a string. So your call to `$.css()` would be more like this:

```
$item.mouseenter(function(event){
  $tooltip
    .show()
    .css({
      left: event.clientX + "px",
      top: '200px'
  }); 
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/uzicek/5/edit

Comment: Wow that was great ty for the demo thats just what i want! :D

Answer (score 4):

You're setting the css property to `event.clientXpx` literally. Put `event.clientX` outside the quotes:

```
 $tooltip.css("left", event.clientX + "px");
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a redone version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/EzdBx/

```
var $tooltip = $('#tooltip')

$('.hover').hover(function(event) {
    //make visible
    $tooltip.show();
    //change left and top values to mouse values
    $(this).bind('mousemove', function(event) {
        $tooltip.css("left", event.clientX);
        $tooltip.css("top", event.clientY);
    })
}, function() {
    $tooltip.hide();
});
```

css:

```
#tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    /* anything you want here and below */
    width: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
$item.mouseover(function (){

  //make visible
  $tooltip.show();

  //change left and top values to mouse values
  $tooltip.css("left","event.clientX + 'px'");
  $tooltip.css("top","200px");         
});
```

with:

```
$item.mouseover(function (){

//make visible
$tooltip.show();

 //change left and top values to mouse values
 $tooltip.css("left",event.clientX + 'px');
 $tooltip.css("top","200px");         
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change its `position` property and probably `z-index` as well.